# How to add margin to a UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, margin

I have a UITableView with a certain background, say red. The view holding the UITableView has a, say, blue background. I want to give the UITableView some left, right, top, and bottom margin so that the blue of the parent view shows on all sides. How do I do that? I tried playing around with `tableView.contentInset` but it's not working.

e.g.

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, -15);
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED TO FIT PROGRAMATIC APPROACH:

Instead of using UItableViewController which has its tableview "stitched to the border",

1) use a normal `UIViewController` subclass

2)make it implement `UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDatasource` protocols

3) declare a tableView property

4)  override viewDidLoad in your viewcontroller and in there, initialize the table view property with a frame smaller than the main view and origin so that there are margins for example {20,20, 280, 440}.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am not using a UITableViewController. More specifically, I want to do this through code, i.e. programmatically. Do you know how this might be done?

Comment: So it seems like you've already implemented steps 1-3 above, you just need to position the frame of the UITableView with the appropriate spacing. I'd recommend using Autolayout.

Comment: Well, he can't figure out how to initialise a simple view in code and add it to view hierarchy, but you suggest auto layout. Aren't you a bit too optimistic?

Comment: I see you are insisting on dismissing/missing the question: that I need to do this programmatically. But thanks for trying to help. I understand the urge to assume people asking questions don't really know what they need. But in my case, I do. :)